# How to mock third party REST web services?

Tags: rest, mocking

I am writing unit test which calls for third party rest end point .
I do not want to rely my test case on environment which is not in my control because URL , credential and data might change with time .

So I want to mock all responses from REST end points 
I checked wiremock and simple 
But what is right approach for such unit tests ? Should we hit actual web service through unit test or mock it ?
If answer is mock it what is best way to do that in JAVA ?

Comment: Are you really writing an unit test or is this an integration test?

Comment: If I am consuming web services from third party and my logic depends on that then I should write unit test for that by mocking third party web service APIs  other wise my unit test will hit those third party web services test environment which might change like URL , credentials , test data

Comment: So you should mock everything necessary for the unit test to pass. Never call a third-party system during unit tests.

Comment: So how to mock REST ends points which are from third party and need to pay for each call

Comment: You should look into available mocking libraries; supposedly, any one of them should be able to mock your REST services.

Answer (score -2):

The best way is to use the actual web service when available for testing to make sure everything is covered including the web service error handling. In case you don't have the service ready or if unable to access from the development env then can go for free mocking services.

You will find lot of providers if you search for that. You can also use http://mockservices.com for mocking REST services.